# Trying to get a button to do setTimeout with a function

Tags: javascript, html

it's my first time trying to use setTimeout and I'm using W3schools as a guideline but I must be going wrong somewhere in the onclick line, What I'm trying to do is delay this function for 5 seconds. This is my code. Any help is much appreciated. If it helps the function works as intended without the setTimeout

```js
function scanalertfunction(id) {
  var divelement1 = document.getElementById(id)

  document.getElementById("scanalertmsg").innerHTML = "Scan Failed! Please try again";
  divelement1.style.display == 'none'
  divelement1.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div id="scanalert" style="display:none;">
  <span class="scanclosebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
  <p id="scanalertmsg"> </p>
</div>
<button onclick="setTimeout(scanalertfunction('scanalert'); 5000);">Ready</button>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` expects a function as first argument, so you have to wrap you `scanalertfunction` => `function() { scanalertfunction(...)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by cyrix, setTimeout expects a function as its argument.  See below for a working solution.

```js
function scanalertfunction(id) {
  var divelement1 = document.getElementById(id)

  document.getElementById("scanalertmsg").innerHTML = "Scan Failed! Please try again";
  divelement1.style.display == 'none'
  divelement1.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div id="scanalert" style="display:none;">
  <span class="scanclosebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
  <p id="scanalertmsg"> </p>
</div>
<button onclick="setTimeout(function() {scanalertfunction('scanalert'); },5000);">Ready</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few syntax errors

check this snippet

```js
function scanalertfunction(id) {
  var divelement1 = document.getElementById(id)

  document.getElementById("scanalertmsg").innerHTML = "Scan Failed! Please try again";
  divelement1.style.display == 'none'
  divelement1.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div id="scanalert" style="display:none;">
  <span class="scanclosebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
  <p id="scanalertmsg"> </p>
</div>
<button onclick="setTimeout(scanalertfunction('scanalert') ,5000);">Ready</button>
```